# How much are mathematics driven by applications?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, philosophy

At some point this provocative question came to my mind:

> Are mathematics mostly driven by applications?

I am taking into account some of the comments made to my original question so I want to make the question more precise. To me it is clear that the answer is NO when we consider only applications outside mathematics. But let us consider also applications inside mathematics.

> Are mathematics mostly driven by applications: whether inside or outside mathematics?

I think that even Hardy would agree that it can become an interesting question if we allow for a *wide* definition of application. I believe this is in part true since many of the "beautiful" results that cannot be used to create new mathematics in other areas or even in the same field are only collected and stored as "mathematical culture". Solving big conjectures on the contrary usually requires mathematicians to develop new powerful tools that are then exploited in other areas.

One historical example of the dissipation of a hot topic from the main mathematical arena is the case of analytic sets. They are still somewhat important in Set Theory, yet, some 80-60 year ago they encouraged incredible mathematicians such as Lusin, Sierpinki or Kuratowski to write long monographs since they believe their existence (which by the way was found by Suslin who found an error in a manuscript by Lebesgue)  was of huge importance. It seems that today only set theorist and some analysts are well-acquainted with the existence of this sets. In the same fashion, the importance of studying Baire functions and meager sets seemed to decay outside set theory as more powerful tools for studying continuity emerged. I also believe Measure Theory became so dominant because it was useful to the theory of integration. So,

> What are examples of discoveries in your fields of study in mathematics that created a revolution (or at least were and are still very important) and were made by the sole motivation of that we call **mathematical beauty**?

I apologize in advance if the question is a nonsense. But I am really interested in trying to answer what is mathematical beauty and how it relates to beauty in other arts and I would like to know what are the topics and who are the mathematicians that did their job not believing it was important for something else but because they found it beautiful.

Comment: You don't use the "¿" sign in English.

Comment: Indeed, I am so sorry. I've changed it.

Comment: This is a delicate question, because I would say the answer is yes, but my notion of application is generous enough that other mathematical problems count as applications.

Comment: Folks around here often say that they do mathematics just "because it's fun", and that applications are neither envisioned nor desired. That's fine with me -- I think mathematics is entertaining and beautiful, too. But I wonder how John Q. Public would react if he found out that his taxes pay for these guys to sit around all day having fun.

Comment: You may be interested in this paper: [A Definition of Mathematical Beauty and Its History](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/vol2/iss2/8/)

Comment: The title and the body ask very different questions! The answer to the title question is obviously "no," of course: a single counterexample suffices and there are many.

Comment: You should also be more specific about what you mean by "application": it's pretty important to distinguish applications within mathematics and applications outside of mathematics.

Comment: @Qiaochu -- "it's pretty important to distinguish applications within mathematics and applications outside of mathematics". Indeed. So-called "applications" within mathematics always feel like cheating, to me -- a bit too parochial and incestuous. Theoretical areas of physics and economics aren't much better. An "application" ought to be something that makes a difference in everyday life -- our cars look nicer, our planes fly faster, with less fuel, our bombs explode better, our diseases are diminished, etc, etc. These (for better or worse) are "applications", in my view.

Comment: There are mathematics which have applications in Physics, and at the same time they are beautiful. So why should we go after beauty only, because we live in real world, but not in dream.

Comment: One could argue that mathematics is driven or advanced by applications but *mathematicians* are driven by beauty.

Comment: @bubba: And the full understanding that a better theory of X will improve theoretical physical understanding of Y, which in turn make the fuel efficiency of cars go higher when applied to Z. How is this not an application motivation? And developing further theory W which can be applied to better understand and develop X in the first place...

Comment: @Asaf -- it's not an "application motivation" because any possible real-world benefits are highly indirect ($W \to X \to Y \to Z$), and possibly even accidental. Theoretical studies in pure mathematics *may* lead to real-world applications, but that is often not the intent of the research. How about your Ph.D. in set theory? Are you working on that because there might be some real-world benefits sometime in the future?

Comment: @bubba: Why do you think **I** personally care about that, or that I am any indication for *everyone else in mathematics*? I don't find it far fetched that someone will set out to learn group theory specifically in order to improve our understanding in crystallography so better graphine sheets can be built. No, not far fetched at all.

Comment: @Asaf -- If you asked group theorists why they study groups, I think the popular answers would be "because it's fun", or "because it's beautiful" or "because it has applications in other areas of mathematics". I think answers like "to improve graphene" would be pretty far down the list.

Comment: @bubba: And how does "popular answer" and "my set theory research" coincide? But on the other hand, in BGU I met postdocs which worked on algebraic graph theory and some algebraic number theory (in the sense of $L$ functions and whatnot), and they originally came from physics or computer science. I agree it's less likely that someone chose mathematics originally for its applications outside of the field, but there are people that rolled around and found themselves studying math because they wanted to solve a problem in real life related topics.

Comment: > I agree it's less likely that someone chose mathematics originally for its applications outside of the field -- Good. Then we're agreed.